# Does URL to REST API have to contain a path?

Tags: rest

The POST method and path /pet is used to add a new pet to the store. And PUT method and path /pet is used to update an existing pet. If adding and updating pets is all the REST API does, does the /pet path have to be used to be RESTful? Or is it also a REST API if the path is removed and the endpoints are implemented as follows:
The POST method and / is used to add a new pet to the store. And PUT method and / is used to update an existing pet. So instead of 
https://www.my-restful-api-pet-store.com/pet 
https://www.my-restful-api-pet-store.com/

Comment: According to the openAPI spec 3 the path may be empty. Personally I would always include the resource name in the path to future proof. [https://swagger.io/specification/#paths-object](https://swagger.io/specification/#paths-object)

Comment: ...Also I think this question is related more to OpenAPI than rest?

Answer (score 1):

> Does URL to REST API have to contain a path?

REST just says "[use resource identifiers](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)".

[HTTP Semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-4.2) defines the two familiar URI schemes

```
http-URI  = "http"  "://" authority path-abempty [ "?" query ]
https-URI = "https" "://" authority path-abempty [ "?" query ]
```

Where [path-abempty](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) is defined by RFC 3986

```
path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar
```

In HTTP/1.1, a [request-line](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) needs a [request-target](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.3), and in [origin-form](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.3.1) you need an [absolute-path](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#appendix-B)

```
absolute-path = 1*( "/" segment )
```

So all of these are fine

```
/
//
//apple
/banana/
```

---

> Any information that can be named can be a [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

If you want to have a single "most recently modified pet" resource in your resource model, that's fine.  And the identifier for that resource can be anything that you want (subject to the production rules described above).

BUT... that resource model gives up a lot of the power that is built into the general purpose [HTTP application protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

Most designs instead choose to have many different cacheable documents, and you send information to the server by editing a specific document.  In other words, instead of sending information to the server by editing the "most recently modified pet" document, we edit the "Doug" document when we are sharing information about Doug.

[Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=1800s) discusses the distinction between using an unbounded set of operations and an unbounded set of resources.

When you are in the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), you'll normally want to take the path with an unbounded set of resources.